# Quickest way to access Map key/value given index

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I generate a random index, like so:

```
const m = new Map();
const r = Math.floor(Math.random()*m.size);
```

now I need to get key with index `r`.

Is this really the fastest way to get the key k?

```
let i = 0;
for(var k of m.keys()){
   if(i === r) {
      break;
    }
  i++;
}
// k is now our randomly selected key
```

Comment: `Array.of(m.keys())[i]`?

Comment: I guess that's less code, not sure if it's more efficient tho

Comment: You may convert the collection of keys to the array once (if the collection doesn't change), and then access the key by index.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not entirely clear on what you’re askingn. Are you trying to find the index of a given key, or are you trying to get a random value out of the map?

Comment: @Paul well a random value out of the map might be just as good, I was trying to do that, by first getting a random key

Comment: Fastest would be keeping an array of keys, that way you can go index -> key -> value

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
const key = [...m.keys()][r];
```

This will save you some lines of code, but from a performance standpoint it might be even slower.

In fact, this [test case](https://jsperf.com/map-loop-vs-keys/1) on JSPerf.com seems to indicate that your version is a *lot* faster (at least on current Chrome and Firefox).